# Is it possible to install Windows 10 on a Raspberry pi 4 using diskpart?

Tags: windows

If it is a 4gb ram model whould it work?

Comment: Microsoft have not released externally a version of Windows 10 that is licenced for use on the Pi - the ARM version is only for OEM or for Windows 'insiders' under very specific licensing conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to write the image to your SD card, but what after that? Do you have a version of Windows that is built to run on ARM hardware? If not, then what is the point of writing it to the SD card?

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Installing Windows 10 or even 11 (currently insider builds only) is possible using projects like *Windows on Raspberry*. Altough Microsoft doesn't support this and they don't want to officially support this, it's only legally possible by fetching the installation files from Windows Update Servers. However, you still need a legally bought licence, like on any other Windows installation.

The entire process is complex, requires a lot of work and you'll need much better hardware than for an averange Linux OS (with GUI). There is also a lack of drivers and software on the PI and you need to work around several things like feature upgrades.

### Detailled answer

If you're not just trying this to learn/play around or for a Software that only runs on Windows and you're not sure to handle all those things, you'll save a lot of time and avoid a lot of issues by just using the standard Raspberry Pi OS or any other Linux distribution which officially supports the RPI. When there is no way to run the app on Linux yet, a (mini) X86 PC will be a much smoother alternative.

But to answer your question: Yes, it is possible with the restrictions above.

There is no simple image because Windows is no free software like Linux. Providing an image would violate Microsofts TOS and is therefore not legal. Furthermore, official licences for Windows 10 ARM are only distributed to OEMs, who are bundeling them to their devices (Source: [Statement of a Microsoft spokesman in *The Verge* from 2020](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/24/21302213/apple-silicon-mac-arm-windows-support-boot-camp) )

But Projects like [WOR (*Windows on Raspberry*)](https://www.worproject.ml/) provides scripts for Windows and Linux to create the desired partition layout on a SD card or SSD. But they cannot provide you ISOs or other installation files from the proprietary Windows OS because Microsoft doesn't allow this.

Downloading the UUP files directly from Microsoft Windows update servers is the only legal way to get them. Two sites can help you doing so: [UUP dump](https://uupdump.net/) and [uup.rg-adguard.net](https://uup.rg-adguard.net/). Please note that they don't provide any files from MS directly for the already mentioned reasons. They'll build you a script which downloads the required files directly from MS. [Here is a tutorial for UUP dump](https://worproject.ml/guides/getting-windows-images). The Raspberry Pi Team confirmed [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=318599#p1907313) that this is legal.

Please note the following:

1. Downloading any pre-configured images (especially pre-activated ones, but images in general) are not legal, so I'd not use those sources and only get them from the official MS servers.
2. Don't think of installing Windows 10/11 as a regular Linux like Raspberry Pi OS! There are many differences, in short: Windows takes **way** more ressources in the entire process and it's much more complicated to setup.
3. You'll need to download a lot of data (e.g. ~9 GB for a single Windows 11 edition), so make sure that enough disk space is avaliable
4. Since there are no pre-configured images, WOR has to do a lot of work to convert the files from the MS update server. This will take time and also CPU ressources (e.g. for extracting). So I'd recommend to have more space than 9 GB for temp files during extracting
5. I'd not use a USB stick to install Windows on it for the Pi. It's mentioned in some posts, but with an average USB stick, this process is EXTREMELY slow. Also fast Micro-SD cards can't really handle Windows to be smooth like on a x86 PC. Better use a SSD (with corresponding converter).
6. There is a lack of driver support, which can be a problem, depending on the use-case. [You can find a status list here](https://github.com/worproject/RPi-Windows-Drivers#status).
7. Also the software is not well supported for Windows on the RPI. Note that you can't just run x86 programs just because it's Windows! The Pi has ARM, which is a completely different architecture. Software must be compiled for ARM to run properly. There are emulating tools, but they're experimental and it will cost performance, which can be a problem since the Pi doesn't have much power and Windows itself already uses a good amount of ressources.
8. Cumulative updates are possible, but feature updates of the full OS [are problematic](https://worproject.ml/guides/performing-os-updates) and doesn't work out of the box, you'll need to apply some workarounds manually.
9. Windows on ARM is still proprietary software. This means: After the trial period, you need a licence to use it legally, like on any x86 machine too when running Windows. [There seems no special licencing restriction for ARM in Microsofts TOS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm), so you should be able to activate it with any legally bought Windows licence.